# How to determine if a Font is a Symbol font (eg Wingdings)

Tags: .net, winforms

Given a `FontFamily` is there a way to determine whether the font is a Symbol font?

I'm trying to display a list of fonts to the user in a Window Forms application, but I want to remove the fonts that are Symbols only so that they can't choose a font that cannot be used.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing that the links are dead, I dug up the code that I used back when I was working on this.

```
Namespace FontManagement

''' <summary>
''' Windows API Logical Font structure to represent information
''' about a font.
''' </summary>
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure LOGFONT
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Height of the font.
    ''' </summary>
    Public lfHeight As Integer
    Public lfWidth As Integer
    Public lfEscapement As Integer
    Public lfOrientation As Integer
    Public lfWeight As Integer
    Public lfItalic As Byte
    Public lfUnderline As Byte
    Public lfStrikeOut As Byte
    Public lfCharSet As Byte
    Public lfOutPrecision As Byte
    Public lfClipPrecision As Byte
    Public lfQuality As Byte
    Public lfPitchAndFamily As Byte
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=32)> _
    Public lfFaceName As String
End Structure


''' <summary>
''' Enumeration of Panose Font Family Types.  These can be used for
''' determining the similarity of two fonts or for detecting non-character
''' fonts like WingDings.
''' </summary>
Public Enum PanoseFontFamilyTypes As Integer
    ''' <summary>
    '''  Any
    ''' </summary>
    PAN_ANY = 0
    ''' <summary>
    ''' No Fit
    ''' </summary>
    PAN_NO_FIT = 1
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Text and Display
    ''' </summary>
    PAN_FAMILY_TEXT_DISPLAY = 2
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Script
    ''' </summary>
    PAN_FAMILY_SCRIPT = 3
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Decorative
    ''' </summary>
    PAN_FAMILY_DECORATIVE = 4
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Pictorial                      
    ''' </summary>
    PAN_FAMILY_PICTORIAL = 5
End Enum


''' <summary>
''' Summary description for FontUtility.
''' </summary>
Public Class Utility

    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure TEXTMETRIC
        Public tmHeight As Integer
        Public tmAscent As Integer
        Public tmDescent As Integer
        Public tmInternalLeading As Integer
        Public tmExternalLeading As Integer
        Public tmAveCharWidth As Integer
        Public tmMaxCharWidth As Integer
        Public tmWeight As Integer
        Public tmOverhang As Integer
        Public tmDigitizedAspectX As Integer
        Public tmDigitizedAspectY As Integer
        <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=1)> _
        Public tmFirstChar As String
        <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=1)> _
        Public tmLastChar As String
        <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=1)> _
        Public tmDefaultChar As String
        <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=1)> _
        Public tmBreakChar As String
        Public tmItalic As Byte
        Public tmUnderlined As Byte
        Public tmStruckOut As Byte
        Public tmPitchAndFamily As Byte
        Public tmCharSet As Byte
    End Structure


    Private Declare Function GetTextMetrics Lib "gdi32" ( _
     ByVal hdc As IntPtr, _
     ByRef lptm As TEXTMETRIC _
     ) As Integer

    Private Declare Function GetOutlineTextMetricsA Lib "gdi32" ( _
     ByVal hdc As IntPtr, _
     ByVal cbData As Integer, _
     ByVal lpOtm As IntPtr _
     ) As Integer

    Private Declare Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32" ( _
     ByVal hdc As IntPtr, _
     ByVal hObj As IntPtr _
     ) As IntPtr



    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the <see cref="PanoseFontFamilyTypes"/> for the specified font.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="graphics">A graphics object to use when detecting the Panose
    ''' family.</param>
    ''' <param name="font">The font to check.</param>
    ''' <returns>The Panose font family type.</returns>
    Public Shared Function PanoseFontFamilyType( _
     ByVal graphics As Graphics, _
      ByVal font As Font) As PanoseFontFamilyTypes
        Dim bFamilyType As Byte = 0

        Dim hdc As IntPtr = graphics.GetHdc()
        Dim hFontOld As IntPtr = SelectObject(hdc, font.ToHfont())

        Dim bufSize As Integer = GetOutlineTextMetricsA(hdc, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
        Dim lpOtm As IntPtr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(bufSize)
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.WriteInt32(lpOtm, bufSize)
        Dim success As Integer = GetOutlineTextMetricsA(hdc, bufSize, lpOtm)
        If Not (success = 0) Then
            Dim offset As Integer = 61
            bFamilyType = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReadByte(lpOtm, offset)

            'byte bSerifStyle = Marshal.ReadByte(lpOtm, offset + 1); 
            'byte bWeight = Marshal.ReadByte(lpOtm, offset + 2); 
            'byte bProportion = Marshal.ReadByte(lpOtm, offset + 3); 
            'byte bContrast = Marshal.ReadByte(lpOtm, offset + 4); 
            'byte bStrokeVariation = Marshal.ReadByte(lpOtm, offset + 5); 
            'byte bArmStyle = Marshal.ReadByte(lpOtm, offset + 6); 
            'byte bLetterform = Marshal.ReadByte(lpOtm, offset + 7); 
            'byte bMidline = Marshal.ReadByte(lpOtm, offset + 8); 
            'byte bXHeight = Marshal.ReadByte(lpOtm, offset + 9); 
        End If

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(lpOtm)

        SelectObject(hdc, hFontOld)
        graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc)

        Return CType(bFamilyType, PanoseFontFamilyTypes)

    End Function

    Private Sub New()

    End Sub

End Class

End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did. Might be not the bst solution but works well:

```
private bool IsSymbol(FontFamily font) {
    Typeface typeface = font.GetTypefaces().First();
    typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out GlyphTypeface glyph);
    return glyph == null || glyph.Symbol;
}
```

The following four fonts will return true eventhough they are not symbol fonts (Global momospace, Global Sans Serif, Global Serif & Global User Interface). So since they all contain the word "Global" and none of the symbol fonts caught by the method contain the word "Global" so I modified the method to exclude the fonts that contain the word "Global" and thus will exclude those 4 only. As follows:

```
private bool IsSymbol(FontFamily font) {
    Typeface typeface = font.GetTypefaces().First();
    typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out GlyphTypeface glyph);
    return (!font.Source.Contains("Global")) && (glyph == null || glyph.Symbol);
}
```

I know this might not be the best solution but works perfectly for me. So you have to check if it works with you or modify it to make it work with the list of Fonts that you have on your system

Answer (score 0):

Posting the solution from the Internet Archive from @user357254 answer.

---

### Detecting if a Font is a Symbol Font

Whilst the Font object provides a good number of properties about a font, there are a few that aren't included. The Panose number of the font is one of them. This property, part of the True Type font definition, can be used for font matching purposes and is also useful for determing information about the type of a particular font (provided the font's author has included the information). The possible values for the Panose number are as follows:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Enumeration of Panose Font Family Types.  These can be used for
  /// determining the similarity of two fonts or for detecting non-character
  /// fonts like WingDings.
  /// </summary>
  public enum PanoseFontFamilyTypes : int
  {
     /// <summary>
     ///  Any
     /// </summary>
     PAN_ANY = 0,
     /// <summary>
     /// No Fit
     /// </summary>
     PAN_NO_FIT = 1,
     /// <summary>
     /// Text and Display
     /// </summary>
     PAN_FAMILY_TEXT_DISPLAY = 2,
     /// <summary>
     /// Script
     /// </summary>
     PAN_FAMILY_SCRIPT = 3,
     /// <summary>
     /// Decorative
     /// </summary>
     PAN_FAMILY_DECORATIVE = 4,
     /// <summary>
     /// Pictorial                      
     /// </summary>
     PAN_FAMILY_PICTORIAL = 5
  }
```

The only function which returns this information is the GDI API call GetOutlineTextMetrics, which returns pretty much anything you would ever want to know about a font and much more. This function returns a difficult C structure which you could adapt using the InteropServices functions but is easier to read simply as a block of memory. Here's the method I used to get the value. The first call to GetOutlineTextMetrics gets the size of the buffer needed to accommodate the entire structure; then the block is allocated and the second call actually gets the values. Once the block has been populated it is then a matter of locating the byte which contains the Panose member, in the case of an ANSI call this is at offset 61 from the start of the structure:

```
  [DllImport("gdi32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
  private static extern int GetOutlineTextMetrics(
     IntPtr hdc,            // handle to DC
     int cbData,            // size in bytes for text metrics
     IntPtr lpOtm         // pointer to buffer to receive outline text metrics structure
     );

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets the <see cref="PanoseFontFamilyTypes"/> for the specified font.
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="graphics">A graphics object to use when detecting the Panose
  /// family.</param>
  /// <param name="font">The font to check.</param>
  /// <returns>The Panose font family type.</returns>
  public static PanoseFontFamilyTypes PanoseFontFamilyType(
      Graphics graphics, Font font)
  {
     byte bFamilyType = 0;

     IntPtr hdc = graphics.GetHdc();
     IntPtr hFontOld = SelectObject(hdc, font.ToHfont());

     int bufSize = GetOutlineTextMetrics(hdc, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
     IntPtr lpOtm = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(bufSize);
     Marshal.WriteInt32(lpOtm, bufSize);         
     int success = GetOutlineTextMetrics(hdc, bufSize, lpOtm);
     if (success != 0)
     {
        int offset = 61;
        bFamilyType = Marshal.ReadByte(lpOtm, offset); 
     }

     Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(lpOtm);

     SelectObject(hdc, hFontOld);
     graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
        
     return (PanoseFontFamilyTypes) bFamilyType;
     
  }
```